# Building a "FileDetails.java" class

Tags: java, file

I need help with the problem below...

Build a class called FileDetails.java.  When you instantiate this class and give it a filename, it will report back the size of the file, whether the file is Readable and whether the file is Writeable; plus any other file information that you might deem important.

This cd goes in main→

FileDetails fd=newFileDetails(“anyfile.doc”);

All other code goes in the constructor.

I have been working on it for hours and so far I have this...(not sure if I'm doing this right at all)

```
import java.io.*;
public class FileDetails {
   //============ Properties ====   
   private boolean e;
   private boolean cr;
   private boolean cw;
   private long s;
   private File f;
   //============ Constructors ==
   public FileDetails(File f) {
      f= new File("anyfile.txt");
   }
   //============ Behaviors =====
   public boolean getExists() {
      e=f.exists();
      return e;
   }

   public boolean getCanRead() {
      cr= f.canRead();
      return cr;
   }

   public boolean getCanWrite() {
      cw= f.canWrite();
      return cw;
   }

   public long getLength() {
      s=f.length();
      return s;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
      FileDetails fd=new FileDetails(new File("anyfile.txt"));
       }
      catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
}
```

I'm just curious as to if there's a better way to do this without all of the methods. The reason i ask is because in the problem stated above i am instructed to put the one provided line of code in the main and everything else in the constructor...
any help with the above problem would be appreciated. as I said, i have been looking for hours with no results. Thank You!

> Blockquote

Comment: Use `new File("anyfile.txt")`

Comment: Use `FileDetails fd=new FileDetails(new File ("anyfile.txt"));`  or better change your constructor so that it accepts a String not a file

Comment: It seems that your constructor should accept a filename as a `String` instead as pointed out by @ScaryWombat

Comment: Awesome! thanks for the help! Any idea if this is the best way (or an ok way) to interrogate a file? is there a way to do it without the methods? the only reason im asking is because in the problem it gives the one line of code and states that everything else should go in the constructor.

Comment: Figured it out... Thanks for the help anyways!!!